# SimpleITK manifest.json file help adding new NIFTI file

Tags: python, simpleitk

I am using `SimpleITK` for image registration purposes. I followed the tutorials and would like to run the program on other brain MRI's now that were not provided in the tutorial. I know I have to add the NIFTI image information to the `manifest.json` file in the data folder inside the TUTORIAL folder but I have limited experience with `.json` files. Does anyone know or can explain what exactly the `.json` file is made up of? Below is a screen shot of

[image: one portion of the .json file]

I know the first item is the file name but not sure about the information inside the curly brackets. I am confused what the "sha512" and the random string of characters are referencing. I want to add a new file but I do not know where to get this information from the NIFTI file to match the format of the `manifest.json` file. Thank you for any help explaining how the .json works and how to add my own file information to it.

Comment: Specifically which example are you trying to run?  One of the Jupyter notebooks in the SimpleITK-Notebooks? That json file is used to download the example data files from the internet. You should be editing that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @DaveChen I am working in the jupyter notebook. I have found a new patient scan from IDA and am hoping to add this NIFTI file to the .json file so the code in the jupyter notebook can run but I am having trouble editing the .json file itself as I am unclear where the string of characters following "sha512" are coming from

Comment: You should edit the Jupyter notebook, not the JSON file.  The sha512 is hash function of each image so it can be found on the Girder repository that stores all the example data. You NIFTI will not be on that servers, so adding it to the JSON file won't work.